# prepend a row to a table but after two tr's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am prepending a row to a table. However, my table has couple of TR's on the top which act has column names etc. When I prepend a new row I want to prepend it AFTER those two TR's. Is this doable?

I am prepending the new row like this:

```
var newrow = "<tr><td>...</tr></td>";
var grid = $('mygrid');
grid.prepend(newrow); I want this prepend to be after two TR's of the grid
```

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery documentation for various DOM manipulation methods? Perhaps another one is better suited for your needs.

Comment: Move your column headers into a thead section where they belong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not wrap your headers inside a `<thead>` and the table body inside a `<tbody>` then you can add the row as the first element inside the `<tbody>`. This would keep your jQuery simple, and your HTML more semantically correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) selector to find the second row of myGrid, then jQuery's [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function to add the new row after the second row in the table:

```
$('#mygrid tr:nth-of-type(2)').insertAfter(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(newrow).insertAfter("tr:nth-child(2)",grid); //assuming grid is the table
```

Answer (score 0):

Anthony,

Why not use thead and tbody tags to separate out your table head and table body. Then you can prepend the rows to the children of tbody. See the following.

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th>aaa</th><th>bbb</th></tr>
        <tr><th>xxx</th><th>yyy</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>stuff</td><td>things</td></tr>
        <tr><td>stuff</td><td>things</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
    <table>
```

Regards,

Peter